# Pass value of html.label to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I need pass the value of @html.label to a variable"data" of controller"Verificar" after click button.

I did:

```
@Html.Label("modalTitle", new { id = "modalTitle" })
<button type="button" class="btn btn-defaultgreen" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Verificar", "Feriado", new { date = @Html.Label("modalTitle", new { id = "modalTitle" }).toString() }, null)'">Create Event</button>
```

but not working this method.... need your helps! thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the "value of @Html.Label"? Labels aren't inputs. From the example you provided, it looks like you want the markup of a label, but why?

Comment: becouse I use FullCalendar v1.6.4 in javascript: case "select">> $('#modalTitle').html(start.toString().substring(0, 15)); there pass the date to @html.label. And now i need pass this date to my controller.

Comment: `@Html.Label()` gives you the name of the property, not its value (a date I assume). What is the control that contains the date you want to pass to the controller.

Comment: What control (html element) contains the date you want to pass to the controller - you need to show your view

Comment: there is my View: [link](http://pastie.org/9684613#)

Comment: Are you saying that your calendar control will update the label with a date, and that you want to then pass that date in on the button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your calendar function to add a data attribute to set the data against the label as a data attribute:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: false,
                events: "/Reglamento/GetEvents/",
                selectable:true,
                select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                    //Bootstrap modal
                    $('#modalTitle').html(start.toString().substring(0, 15));
                    //Add data attribute - can have better date format here (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd)
                    $('#modalTitle').data("startdate", start.toString().substring(0, 15);
                    $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                }
            });
```

Update your button to call a function that grabs the data attribute, constructs the url and sets the location:

```
function NavigateByDate()
{
    var date = $('#modalTitle').data("startdate");

    //this could be done better...should show the intention though
    var url = '@Url.Action("Verificar", "Feriado")' + '?data=' + date;
    location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: hello, i don't understand this line>> var url = '@Url.Action("Verificar", "Feriado"' + '?data=' + date';

Comment: That is generating your url based on the action that you are running, and passed the date that was added to the data attribute of the label in.

Comment: should be this??
var url = '@Url.Action("Verificar", "Feriado" )' + '?data=' + date;